# Create array of object class in JavaScript

Tags: typescript

Suppose I have this class:

```
class Car {
  constructor(brand) {
    this.carname = brand;
  }
  present() {
    return "I have a " + this.carname;
  }
}
```

I need to create an array with the objects of this class, for this I am using:

```
mycar : Car[] = new Car[2];
mycar[0] = new Car("Ford");
mycar[1] = new Car("Renault");
```

But it's not working, how do I do this?

Comment: `mycar : Car[] = new Car[2];` Is that JavaScript?

Comment: Are you perhaps using TypeScript? You don't need to specify types for an array in regular JS, they can hold any combination of objects or primitives.

Comment: specifically this line I don't know so I'm in doubt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
class Car {
  constructor(brand) {
    this.carname = brand;
  }
  present() {
    return "I have a " + this.carname;
  }
}

var cars  = [];
cars[0] = new Car("ford");
cars[1] = new Car("bmw");

console.log(cars[0].present()); // I have a ford
console.log(cars[1].present()); // I have a bmw
```

Answer (score 2):

To create a new array in Typescript all you have to do is this: `mycar : Car[] = [];`
and to add cars to this array you should use `mycar.push(new Car("Subaru"));`.